# Reading data from a flowmeter on a microcontroller

Tags: communication, ethernet, serial-communication, raspberry-pi-pico, communication-protocol

For a personal DIY project, I want to make an app that measure water consumption and send the data to an API.

I have the Keyence FD-Q50C clamp on flowmeter that has a screen to display the data.
The flowmeter can be connected to the IO Link Master module Keyence NQ-MP8L which has a M12 to Ethernet cable that can transmit the data. Keyence offers the NQ Sensor Monitor software to configure the NQ-MP8L, by linking the module to my PC with the Ethernet cable I managed to configure the IP of the module.

Now I would like to read the data on a microcontroller. On the NQ-MP8L datasheet, it is said that the module is compatible with different data sending protocol: Ethernet/IP, Modbus, Profinet.

I first wanted to see the data format so I used Wireshark and I observed that I was receiving some CIP packets from the module (I don't have a pipe on which I can plug the flowmeter so I don't know if it would send some different data with a flow or if it send data even when the flow is null).

I have now some difficulties to understand how the data are transmitted and their format in order to read them on a microcontroller. I have a microntroller (W5500 EVB Pico) with an Etheret Port on which I can plug the NQ-MP8L but I am open to suggestions.

Here are the datasheets :
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tGxoTztU6-aOUp8EyHqI-dLpJ0zSU3lD?usp=sharing
(I also added the datasheet of the FD-Q50C just in case)

If someone has any idea of how I ccan do read those data I would be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Communicating using ethernet is likely more complicated than is required.  Rather than communicating with the NQ-MP8L, directly connect to the flow sensor.

[image: Pinout]

The datasheet shows that there is a 4-20mA analog output, which can be [trivially read](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/18790) with an ADC or a dedicated current loop receiver.

Alternately, it appears to be configurable for a pulse output, which can be easily received on a digital pin, then integrated (summed) in software.

[image: Image showing pulse output]

Alternately, the IOLink pin is asynchronous serial at 38.4kbps, which is easily received by a microcontroller.

If you prefer to use ethernet, Modbus/TCP is a standard format which likely has libraries available for your ethernet stack.

Comment: I thank you a lot for your answer, for a lack of materiel I first focused on the IO Link module and forgot about this possiblity. I have a battery that powers my flowmeter through a four wires cable, in the OUT + Analog output PNP mode, I can power the flowmeter with the brown and black  wires and read the data with the white and blue wires, am I right ?

Comment: I read the diagram as brown+blue being 24v and ground. Black and white are configurable outputs/input. In the simplest use, Connect brown to battery +, blue to battery -, blue to one leg of an ammeter, white to the other leg of an ammeter, and configure the device for analog output. Leave black unconnected.